# Javascript HTML5 FileAPI: Uncaught ReferenceError: utils is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I can't find this anywhere, and no one else has this problem that I know of.

I'm using the code straight off http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/ and I can't get it to work at all.

Here's the jsfiddle I've been using to test it out http://jsfiddle.net/4k5xa/

Comment: What is `utils` is it suppose to be part of `dojo`?

Comment: I have no clue, but it's straight from the w3 site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is not a complete, working example. It calls hypothetical library functions. You will need to implement them or not use them.

Comment: so how would I go about taking the source out of chinese?